# PHP REGEX: space & line break in paramters (custom tags)

Tags: php, regex

this is my custom tag

```
[extract=A:B(

   <div>
       <p>Some content...</p>
   </div>

)]
```

- The word *extract* stays as it is.
- Value A has a string input (one word no spaces, no line breaks)
- Value B will contain html closed in (). it will contain line breaks

I am not good with regular expressions but this is basically what I want.

```
\/[extract=(.*?):(.*?)/]\
```

I need the appropriate pattern query and a *foreach loop*, preg_match_all(), to return **A** & **B**

Comment: Can _"Some content..."_ contain ) and/or ]? Will B always contain HTML tags in the form <thetag>_Some content possibly including other tags_</thetag>? Do you care about what is outside the <thetag>...</thetag> between the (...) in B?

Comment: Creating a set of custom mark-up tags in a language that's effectively a template language in the first place. Interesting...

Comment: @RobertB: yes, I am even going to use custom tags that contan [] within B

Comment: Per middarparka's comment, I would *strongly* urge you to do the whole thing in XML, or at least to use PHP's native [serialization functionality](http://php.net/serialize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/\[extract=(?<class>\w+):(?<method>\w+)\((?<html>.*?)\)\]/s', $content, $matches);
print_r($matches['class']);
print_r($matches['method']);
print_r($matches['html']);
```

Should output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
)
Array
(
    [0] => B
)
Array
(
    [0] => 

   <div>
       <p>Some content...</p>
   </div>

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your question. Where should the string input for "A" be? In the place of letter "A"?

If this is what you want, then the solution is:

`preg_match_all('/\[extract=([^\s]+?):(.+)\]/s', 'your custom tag', $result);`

So what you might be looking for is the modifier `s` which modifies the dot (".") character's meaning so to include linebreaks.

I also recommend you http://www.regular-expressions.info/ if you want to get more familiar with regular expressions.

Comment: yes, the A is a class instance, B is a method that contains HTML code as a parameter

Comment: I see, so you can use the expression I wrote, it'll produce exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be perfect, but seems to work in very quick and limited testing. If nothing else, it might help you get to a better solution.

`/^(?:\[extract=)(\w)+:(\w+\(.*\))\]$/s`

Note that the trailing `s` flag is used to make the dot match all characters including new lines.